# Hazelcast, IMap locking keys in the cluster

Tags: java, synchronization, locking, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am new with using Hazelcast. I am using Hazelcast 3.6-EA as data storage in my web application. The applilcation is going to be run on several instances, therefore I need to implement locking mechanizm to avoid [race conditions](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#locking-maps), when several threads try to work with the same Map.

The desire behaviour would be following: The first one insance that start working with the Map should lock it and perform needed updates. The the other one insance should see that Map is locked and skip performing any updates.

So, the main benefit of such locking should be avoid execution of the same code twice.

```
public void consumePerformances(Date date) {
    Collection<Integer> performancesId = timeformPerformanceService.getPerformancesIds();
    timeFormService.getPerformancesByMeetingDate(date, new DataCallback<List<Performance>>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(List<Performance> performances) {
        Map<Integer, Performance> newPerformancesMap =
            performances.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Performance::getPerformanceId, Function.identity()));
        newPerformancesMap.entrySet().stream().filter(element -> performancesId.contains(element.getKey()))
            .forEach(element -> element.getValue().setUpdateDate(date));
         timeformPerformanceService.save(newPerformancesMap.values());
      }

      @Override
      public void onError(Throwable throwable) {

      }
    });
  }

 public void save(Collection<Performance> performances) {
    LOGGER.info("Save performances to the hazelcast");
    IMap<Integer, Performance> map = hazelcastInstance.getMap(PERFORMANCE_CACHE_NAME);
    performances.forEach(item -> {
      try {
        if (map.tryLock(item.getPerformanceId(), 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, 300, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
          try {
            map.put(item.getPerformanceId(), item);
          } finally {
            try {
              map.unlock(item.getPerformanceId());
            } catch (IllegalMonitorStateException e) {
              LOGGER.error("Lock was released, due to lease time was expired");
            }
          }
        } else {
          LOGGER.info("Lock on key: {} is not released yet", map.get(item.getPerformanceId()));
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Lock error. Key could not be equal to null");
      }
    }
    );
  }
```

I have a doubts if I understand the locking mechanism correctly and if the implemented behaviour above gives me the desired results.

I'll appreciate for any detail explanation.

Also, tell me what behavior will be in case whe on thread lock the map, and the other one is performing just `get(key)` operation?

Comment: First of all 3.6-EA is outdated and an early-access version. The current version is 3.6.5, or actually 3.7. Apart from that why not send an operation to the key-owner and execute it right on the spot? That way you could prevent locking since everything is sent to a single cluster member.

Comment: @noctarius. I'll update the version. "Apart from that why not send an operation to the key-owner and execute it right on the spot?" - Could you explain it more detail and why it is better then locking?

Comment: If you use an EntryProcessor (and your operation is reasonably slow) you can inject it into the actual workflow of the key. It will be handled like any other get / set / ... operation. There is no concurrency for this very key in that situation.